# Adding a lagre number of MapIcon to Map in Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

There is a problem in Windows Phone 8.1 App, where I have to add about 2000 MapIcons to map:

```
while (r.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
{
    ...
    Map.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
}
```

This code is executing very slowly, about 10 seconds only for 250 pins, and blocks any user input.
I tried to create async method with no result, it seems that the logic inside the method `Map.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);` is executed always in main thread. Is there any way to maybe call some function to process UI in while cycle?

EDIT: The slowlest part of the code is `Map.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);`, when I remove it, the code is executing <1 second.

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider other solutions like clustering or dynamic tile generation in order to keep the map readibility and performances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding `await Task.Delay(1);` in cycle body and making this method `async`. So the whole code is:

```
async void update()
{
    ...
    while (r.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
    {
        ...
        Map.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Nicolas mentioned you might want to consider adding clustering when working with a lot of pushpins. I have a clustering solution for Windows Phone 8.1 available as part of this spatial toolbox library: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/